# Jekyll: Redirect from URLs containing colons

Tags: jekyll

I am currently converting a MediaWiki site to Jekyll (GitHub Pages). Unfortunately, MediaWiki category pages have URLs containing a colon ":" :

```
http://www.example.com/Category:Name_Of_Category
```

I would like to redirect these old URLs to new Jekyll pages with URLs in the form of:

```
http://www.example.com/name_of_category/
```

Therefore, I used `redirect_from` in the front matter of `name_of_category.md`, but Jekyll fails to build as the generated static html file containing the redirect has a colon in the file name:

```
Error: Protocol error @ rb_sysopen - /www.example.com/_site/Category:Category_Name.html
```

Encoding the colon results in the same error message. I tried:

```
redirect_from: /Category%3ACloud_Application_Architectures
redirect_from: /Category&#58;Cloud_Application_Architectures
```

Finally, I included a file `Category%3ACloud_Application_Architectures.html` in the jekyll page folder. It is added to `_site` during build, but when browsing to `http://www.example.com/Category:Category_Name` a "Not Found" error is returned.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Using a separate webserver with ProxyPass redirection to GitHub handling the redirects in the .htaccess file would only be my last resort. After all, I am trying to get rid of maintaining a server for the site ;-)

Comment: Tested on jekyll 3.1.x, work perfectly. Can you paste the output of `jekyll build --trace` ?

Comment: I would go with the ProxyPass solution or something similar. The colon ":" is a reserved character so even if you manage to get Jekyll to create a file with a colon in it (on Linux), you won't be able to rebuild your site on OSX or Windows machines... And the same applies for hosting.